# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead Im not sure where I am going wrong

Tags: reactjs

I am getting the error as- Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {itemname, imageUrl, subitems}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

this is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import reactDom from 'react-dom';
import DATA from '../../components/data/data';
import Itemcard from './homepage-directory';

 class Homepage extends React.Component  {
     constructor(){
         super();
         this.state={
             menu:DATA
         };
     }
render(){
  
    
    return(
        <div className = 'homepage' >
            {
                this.state.menu.map(
                    ({id, ...otherprops}) => <Itemcard key={id} {...otherprops}/>
                )
            }
            <h1>lololol</h1>

        </div>
    )
}
 }
 export default Homepage;
```

this is the other component:

```
import react from 'react';
import './homepage-directory.styles.scss';

const Itemcard = (itemname, key, imgUrl ) =>(
    <div className='itemcard'
        style={{
            backgroundImage: `url(${imgUrl})` }}
    >
        <div>
            <h2> {itemname} </h2>
       </div>
    </div>
)

export default Itemcard;
```

and this is my data-

```
 const DATA = [
     {  id:1,
        itemname:'brownie',
        imageUrl:'https://i.ibb.co/XJ53VVd/nutella-brownie.jpg',
        subitems:[]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using wrong props. you need to update your code like this:

```
const Itemcard = ({ itemname, key, imgUrl }) =>(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is complaining because you are not destructuring it in a correct way.

1. Destructuring it at function defination.It can be achieved while you define your params.This approach is not recommended if you have lot of props as it decreases the readablity,but in your case it is fine.

   > const Itemcard = ({ itemname, key, imgUrl }) =>{ ...component
   > }
2. If you find this more complicated simply use props as a param and structure inside the component as and when needed

> ```
> const Itemcard = (props) => {
>   const { itemname, key, imgUrl, rest } = props;
> };
> ```

3. Plain old props.yourProps